# Unable to update a Pivot filter VBA MS Excel 2007

Tags: excel, vba

I am having a problem with updating a pivot filter progmatically in VBA.  What I want to do is filter the pivot with the latest date on my recordset (I am getting my data from a Jet database). I have tried the code below for MS Excel 2010 and works fine. I also have tried this on an Excel 2007 on one of our computers and works fine as well. However, when I deployed it on my clients PC, it returns an "Error 1004: Application defined or object defined error" on the last line of the code below.  The odd thing is my client has Excel 2007..

Do you guys have an idea why this is happening?

```
        ActiveSheet.PivotTables(sPivotName).PivotFields(sPivotField).CurrentPage = "(All)"
        ActiveSheet.PivotTables(sPivotName).PivotFields(sPivotField).ClearAllFilters
        ActiveSheet.PivotTables(sPivotName).PivotFields(sPivotField).CurrentPage = CStr(rsDate("MaxValue"))
```

Comment: Are your regional settings the same as your client's? Setting page fields with date values is extremely tricky in non US regions.

Comment: No, they are different.  Mine uses US date system (mm/dd/yyyy) and the client uses Europe date system (dd/mm/yyyy). But I checked that the filter contains the same date string, for example "11/2/2015" is the latest date, "11/2/2015" is also on the list of available values on the filter. Or the excel on my client's PC interpret it as "2/11/2015"?

Comment: We have changed the date format of the client's PC to the US date system (mm/dd/yyyy). The error is still there. Do you have ideas on this?

Comment: I was able to solve this by just upgrading the Excel on the client's PC to Excel 2010. Though I still have no idea why it does not work on Excel 2007.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this by just upgrading the Excel on the client's PC to Excel 2010. Though I still have no idea why it does not work on Excel 2007.